# R: How to colapse a list of list (from str_split) into just one list and preserve some row data?

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr, stringr

The output from str_split generates a list. How can the list of list be collapsed into a flat list?

See the sample data below:

```
library(magrittr)   
library(dplyr)


url='https://github.com/macarthur-lab/clinvar/raw/master/output/clinvar.tsv.gz'
w=readr::read_tsv(url) #warnings can be safely ignored
w<-w %>% filter(grepl('LabCorp',all_submitters))
#traits are separated by semicolons
ttd<-stringr::str_split(w$all_traits,pattern = ';')
#there are several traits per row from str_split
ttd.l<-sapply(ttd,length)
#sample
ttd[[77]]
[1] "Hereditary cancer-predisposing syndrome"
[2] "Lynch syndrome"                         
[3] "Lynch Syndrome"                         
[4] "Neoplastic Syndromes, Hereditary"       
[5] "Hereditary non-polyposis colon cancer"  
#how to put all 'all-traits' into single vector
```

This does not seem to do it:

```
traits<-lapply(ttd,c)
table(traits)
```

EDIT: The problem with simple unlist(ttd) is that I need to preserve the row's ID in w$measureset_id

Like so:

```
out=data.frame()
for (i in 1:length(ttd)) {
  print(i)
  #unlist(ttd[[i]])
  one<-data.frame(id=w[i,'measureset_id']
                   ,trait=unique(toupper(unlist(ttd[[i]]))))
  out<-rbind(out,one)
}
```

head(out,5)

```
  measureset_id                          trait
1         36663             CARDIAC ARRHYTHMIA
2         36663                     ARRHYTHMIA
3         12779 PHEOCHROMOCYTOMA/PARAGANGLIOMA
4         12779               PHEOCHROMOCYTOMA
5         12779               PARAGANGLIOMAS 4
```

Comment: Does `unlist` do what you want?

Comment: Would `unlist()` do what you need?

Comment: Is `unlist()` what you're after? (snide). Or actually, instead of splitting, you can probably do `ttd <- scan(text = w$all_traits, sep = ";", what = "")`

Comment: OP: The reproducible example was useful, but in future try to specify what packages you are using (readr and dplyr). Others: when adding a comment it does suggest you don't use the comment to answer a question.

Comment: Okay, in light of additional information what the OP wants, I'm adding new answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In light of your additional information what you want, here are a couple of ways to do it. I'm jumping in at the point in your code immediately before you create ttd because that is just making life hard for yourself.

```
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)

#First, create a useful function
getTraits <- function(x) data_frame(trait=unique(unlist(strsplit(x$all_traits, split=";"))))

#Method 1 using plyr
traits <- ddply(w, .(measureset_id), getTraits)
head(traits)
#  measureset_id                                        trait
#1           788                 Sudden infant death syndrome
#2           788                           Brugada syndrome 2
#3           788 Primary familial hypertrophic cardiomyopathy
#4           788                 Sudden Infant Death Syndrome
#5           788                               Cardiomyopathy
#6           788                             Long QT syndrome
traits[traits$measureset_id == 36663, ]
#     measureset_id              trait
#3231         36663 Cardiac arrhythmia
#3232         36663         Arrhythmia

#Method 2 using dplyr
traitsd <- w %>% group_by(measureset_id) %>% do(getTraits(.))
head(traitsd)
#Source: local data frame [6 x 2]
#Groups: measureset_id [1]
#
#  measureset_id                                        trait
#          (int)                                        (chr)
#1           788                 Sudden infant death syndrome
#2           788                           Brugada syndrome 2
#3           788 Primary familial hypertrophic cardiomyopathy
#4           788                 Sudden Infant Death Syndrome
#5           788                               Cardiomyopathy
#6           788                             Long QT syndrome
traitsd[traitsd$measureset_id == 36663, ]
#Source: local data frame [2 x 2]
#Groups: measureset_id [1]
#
#  measureset_id              trait
#          (int)              (chr)
#1         36663 Cardiac arrhythmia
#2         36663         Arrhythmia
```

Comment: Thank you. Having 2 methods is a great answer. I try to use dplyr a lot so I very much like your method 2. there is always only one row per measureset_id. But the group_by is there to tell dplyr what to go by (I guess).

Answer (score 3):

Your ttd is a list of character vectors. If what you want is a character vector of length 3992 of all elements then you just want

```
traits <- unlist(ttd)
```